# How i Show DateTime in Label

Tags: c#

I have a `label`, a `textbox` and a `button` on a `form`. I want to add days to the current date/time. The value of days is connected to the `textbox` and the `datetime` is shown on the `label`.

```
Double ce = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text)
DateTime cs = DateTime.Now.AddDays(ce)
```

But it throws an error that the input is wrong.

Comment: Which errors do you get?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: are you sure the text from textBox1 can be converted to a double??

Comment: Which input? text box text is not a double? Use Double.TryParse

Comment: is it a compiler error or a runtime error, and on which line is it?

Comment: Why the downvote? It is a perfectly valid question for a beginner.

Comment: @gauravvgat It has nothing to do with what the question is.  The downvote came from a combination of not telling us what sort of error there is, and not sticking around to answer clarifications about the error.  We're left to guess at what can potentially be causing the problem.

Comment: But the user may have gone AFK or offline. Please take that into consideration for new users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1.aspx) you can check if the value in the string is ok to be converted. If it is not you can inform the user something went wrong.

```
Double days = 0;
DateTime cs= DateTime.Now;
bool daysOk = Double.TryParse(textbox1.Text, out days);
if (daysOk) 
{
   cs = cs.AddDays(days);
}
else
{
   textbox1.Text = "invalid days";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT* Added Parse instead of Tryparse to show error instead of adding 0 days

```
        try
        {
            double days = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            label1.Text = DateTime.Now.AddDays(days).ToLongDateString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "error"); }
```

Comment: will still fail if `textbox1.Text` can't be converted to a double

Comment: @Sam Well either he wants an error and uses parse, or adds 0 days if its wrong and uses tryparse, anyway edited the answer